# PDO login page, select a specified rows when user is connected and do something with it

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, pdo

I want to create a public function where I select from the database the user row "privilege". If "privilege" is "agent", then echo something, if "privilege" is "concessionnaire", echo something else. So I am trying to figure out what's wrong here.. I am not sure if I am selecting the right thing in my sql query..I am kinda stuck here! Any help would be nice!!

```
public function Access(){
        $st = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE privilege=?');
        $st->bindParam(3, $privilege);
        $st->excute();

        if($st->rowCount() == 1 && $privilege == 'agent') {
            echo 'Vous etes un agent.';
        } elseif ($st->rowCount() == 1 && $privilege == 'concessionnaire') {
            echo 'Vous etes un concessionnaire.';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `WHERE privilege=NULL`? (Which will always evaluate to `NULL`, so _false_, even when there are `NULL` privilege values). There is no `$privilege` variable in scope, so that will be effectively what it does.

Comment: instead of "SELECT * FROM users WHERE privilege=?" I would select the privilege of a specific user wich is sent as parameter. eg: Select privilege from users where username =?" bindParam(1, $username);The problem with your query may be also the bindParam. It should be (1,$privilege), not 3

Comment: there is no point in testing st->rowCount twice. `if($st->rowCount() == 1) { switch ($privilege) { case 'agent': ...; case '...' }`

Comment: this is kinda cunfusing, what does this have to do? If you whant to know user privilege level, than this query is so wrong...

Comment: No Benedictus, All I want is like Andrei Andrei said : Select a specified user which is sent as parameter, and then select privilege froms users ...etc

Answer (score 0):

There's a slight problem... if you know in advance what the privilege is, why do you wait till after the query to verify the value? I think in fact your desired query is something like:

```
$st = $this->db->prepare('SELECT privilege FROM users WHERE id=?'); // id, or your unique column
```

then, bindValue to your parameter. Since the statement won't be reused, no need to bind to param.

```
$id = ''; // just make sure $id exists, as $privilege should in your example
$st->bindValue(1, $id); // since there's only one parameter, don't write 3
$st->excute();
```

you could also do it in one step:

```
$st->excute(array($id));
```

otherwise, even though it's less efficient to use rowCount() two times as Marc B commented, this might work. then, retrieve your value:

```
$privilege = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```